# editing injected parameter without returning value c#

Tags: c#, function, object

I have a question: is it possible to edit the entry of the function without returning any value and those entries will be edited?

Idea:

```
void AddGreeting(string value)
{
    value = "Hi " +value;
}
```

and calling this function like this:

```
string test = "John"; 
AddGreeting(test);
//and here the test will be "Hi John"
```

is that possible? and how to do it if it is?

Comment: [ref - C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: Note that as strings are immutable you aren't *actually* modifying value, rather assigning it to a *new* string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use the ref parameter as so:

```
void AddGreeting(ref string value){}
```

and this would do what you want:

```
void AddGreeting(ref string value)
{
    value = "Hi " +value;
}

string test = "John"; 
AddGreeting(ref test);
```

Alternatively, you could return a string, which i would consider neater and cleaner to look at

Comment: Note that as strings are immutable you aren't *actually* modifying value, rather assigning it to a *new* string.

Comment: I would agree that returning a value is easier to read.  I will use ref if I need to modify multiple variables, but that is rare as well as in those cases I am usually modifying a class property or will pass in an object that has multiple properties.

Comment: thank you, I guess that will answer my questions. I am trying to write a code to read the string parameters of a generic object  and delete sql injection and return the same object.

Comment: have youi thought of using reflection instead?